Teleport action and blindsight
I would like to create a monster that have a blindsight of 120 feet and that is blind beyond this radius. Can I give this monster a teleportation action? This action is usually described as follows (emphasis mine):

The monster magically teleports, along with any equipment it is wearing or carrying, up to 120 feet to an unoccupied space it can see.

Obviously this description doesn't fit for a blinded monster. So maybe I could readjust the description as follows:

The monster magically teleports, along with any equipment it is wearing or carrying, up to 120 feet to an unoccupied space.

Does it make sense? Is this in contrast with something in the manuals?

Teleport works as normal within the range of blindsight
This is covered by an entry in the Sage Advice Compendium:

Can a blinded creature make an opportunity attack? An opportunity attack is triggered by “a hostile creature you can see” (PH, 195). If you can’t see an enemy, you can’t make an opportunity attack against it. Creatures with blindsight are an exception to this rule, because that ability lets those creatures “see” within a certain radius.

Because blindsight is treated as sight for its interactions with other sight-based rules, your blind monster could teleport anywhere within the limit of its blindsight, without changing the standard description of the teleport ability.
